# Editing data in QGIS Server via WFS in AutoCAD Map (2015)

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server, autocad-map

I have a QGIS Server up and running. I can consult my layers using WMS protocol and edit them using WFS protocol in QGIS or lizmap web client for example, but I am not able to make it work in AutoCAD Map. These are the steps I follow:

[image]

[image]

In the third screenshot you can see the layer is added to the workspace but the layer is totally empty: it has no geometric data and no alphanumeric data.

I am getting the following errors in the messages window:

```
Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Error al conectar.
Error al abrir la conexión FDO.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Error al conectar.
Error al abrir la conexión FDO.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Error al conectar.
Error al abrir la conexión FDO.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Ha surgido un problema al acceder a la información de esquema de la conexión.
Project file error: Error reading the project file


Error al conectar.
Error al abrir la conexión FDO.
Project file error: Error reading the project file
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.
The way i solved this was to set the version in you're first image to version 1.0.0 (even if the wfs isn't version 1.0.0)